# Opening a post request in a new tab

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

What I want to do in Angular is open a new tab and post data to it at the same time. This works great with creating a form element and submitting the form. The only issue is every input in a form MUST have a name. In my case I can't have names, I need to write a JSON string directly as post input data. Using `$http` in Angular does this to the input data by default.
On PHP side that means reading from `"php://input"` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Do you have control of the page you are trying to POST to?

Comment: I think, it's not possible. Because, when you open new tab it's GET.

Comment: I could change the backend as well, yes. But I don't want to put in a special case just for this if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i misunderstood the question because i didn't have experience with angular but:

you could open a new tab and call "newTabPage.php" and in this file you send your request (with ajax) to get your data.

Comment: Like a proxy script in the middle? It would work but it also makes things too complicated.

Comment: i think anyway that [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](ajax) is the key for your problem :)

Comment: The current solution is built on ajax and showing the results in a textarea. What I want now is to get the results into a separate tab/window, preserving headers and everything.